# How can I fix 'Access denied' error in visual studio 2012 and VS community 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I wish to learn the `C++` programming language. I have `Visual Studio 2012` and `VS community 2015`. I started programming the standard 'hello world' program in VS 2012.

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    cout << "I'm learning C++!" << endl;
    cout << "This is fun :D" << endl;

    cin.get();
}
```

When I proceeded to debugging I received an error:

`"Unable to start program (*program name & location*) Access is denied"`. I downloaded `VS 2015` version in another attempt and received the same error.

I have been searching for solutions for hours and a lot of posts mention having the incorrect permissions set - if this is the problem, how do I fix it?

Please can anyone help?

Your answers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Turn on windows service :- Application experience
- Computer (right-click) -> manage -> Service & Application -> service -> Enable Application experience

Hope This Might Solve Your Problem.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, Application experience is already "running". The Startup Type is "Manual (Trigger Start)". Should I make any changes to this? Would a restart be suitable?